# How to check for specific condition in within a rows in excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I have a situation which is mentioned below

[Problem Statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdvA7.png)

want to check if say Order ID: 835093 and Order Status is NO_ANSWER for every Sr.No up to 7 then I want to consider it as Yes otherwise No, for order ID: 735093, the output should be No as Order Status is multiple not unique

Comment: Please see [how-to-ask-a-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  You should put more effort into writing your question, explain it better and show us what you have tried. Thanks+

Answer (score 0):

this is an array formula, so press Shift+Ctrl+Enter simultaneously when entering it.

```
=IF(SUM(IF(B$2:B$18=E2, 1/COUNTIFS(B$2:B$18,E2,C$2:C$18,C$2:C$18),""))=1,"Yes","No")
```

Paste it to G2, make it an array formula and then copy and paste it to G3.

Answer (score 0):

Try below-

```
=IF(COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER($C$2:$C$9,$B$2:$B$9=E2)))>1,"No","Yes")
```

[image]